# Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll is always empty

Tags: node.js

I have a node project using puppeteer.
I run the following code in console and I get 170 results back

```
circlenod = window.document.querySelectorAll('area[templateid="ucChart_pnlip"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < circlenod.length; i++) {
        console.log('circlenod --> : ', circlenod[i]);
    }
```

However when I try to use page evaluate in puppet or $$ method, I get no results coming back

```
let test;
let list = await page.$$('area[templateid="ucChart_pnlip"]');
console.log('list ===> ', list); ===> this is empty
await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('coming in ??'); ==> never see this 
    test = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('area[templateid="ucChart_pnlip"]'));
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        console.log('circlenod --> : ', test[i]); ==> never see this
    }
 })
 console.log('test', test); ==> undefined
```

This is an example of the element. How can I extract this information from the attribute after looping through all the `<area />` `fields="date|5/1/2020|14"`

```
<area shape="poly" coords="802,235,807,233,807,241,802,243" fields="date|5/1/2020|14" templateid="ucChart_pnlip" href="../../../../../../UserControls/History/Single/#" onclick="charttip_Show(this, event);return false" alt="">
```

Comment: window.document.querySelectorAll('area[templateid="ucChart_pnlip"]') vs page.$$('area[templateid="=ucChart_pnlip"]'). there seems to be a `=` too much in your puppeteer code.

Comment: @acincognito sorry that was just my typo here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this, I am putting this out there for whoever needs it. when you get array of elements, you need to spicify the attribute of the element that you want

```
let test= await page.evaluate((sele) =>{

    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sele))
    let links = elements.map(element=>{
        return element.getAttribute('fields');
    })
    return links;
    },'area[templateid="ucChart_pnlip"]')

console.log(test)
```